# Importing Graphs from external simulating software to Word Document

Tags: python, ms-word

I looking to automate the process where I am supposed to the run the simulation to study around 100 different charts, and then exporting them to the word file. The simulating software has a automation function, but I have to every time do this process manually.

Comment: Are you asking for a tool that would do that for you? Or way to access APIs or something? Without giving any details I doubt anyone can give any ideas.

Comment: Yes, it's like interfacing a simulating software with the Python to simulate the data from external software.

Comment: So, how is python actually involved in this? I still didn't understand

Comment: I want to use Python for automation purpose to save the simulated plots of the external software to the computer directory, and from there importing all the saved plots to word document. Doc will be having a single plot on single page. Right now, I have to copy and paste every single plot from the external software to word file manually.

Comment: I don't really see how you could do that on python, or at least not easily. There's probably software for doing macros on Windows(?) -- or maybe software testing software, that is used for clicking things etc. which sounds to me like something you'll need.